# Parsing JSON page

Tags: c#, json

Been trying to figure out how to parse out **"in_reply_to_status_id_str -> id_str"** form the twitter search page:

https://twitter.com/phoenix_search.phoenix?q=hello&headers%5BX-Twitter-Polling%5D=true&headers%5BX-PHX%5D=true&since_id=203194965877194752&include_entities=1&include_available_features=1&contributor_details=true&mode=relevance&query_source=unknown

Anyone that could write a small example to show how it can be done?

Comment: You are going to have to get a Dynamic Json Converter, then you will have to loop through each of the objects pulling them apart. Have you tried that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object This is a great example

Comment: I cant get that to work, tried but getting errors all over the place

Comment: What type of errors have you received? I just used this the other day to basically do the same thing except not from twitter but from TeamCity.

Comment: Could you post an example? :)

Comment: Sure let me grab what I used to get my Json.

Comment: I posted my working example, I put what I get from the Json, through an ajax call in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, trying to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
dynamic jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(new WebClient().DownloadString("your url"));
foreach (var item in jObj.statuses)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.in_reply_to_status_id_str, item.id_str);
}
```

Comment: how would i print that into a messagebox instead of into the console?

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(item.in_reply_to_status_id_str.ToString() + " " +  item.id_str.ToString());`. You may need to check whether `item.xxx` is null before calling `ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

SO here is where I pull my Json, this is where my list gets made, which you all ready have:

```
public JsonResult AllStatuses() //from the json called in the _client view
    {
        var buildStatuses = new List<BuildStatus>();
        var projects = Client.AllProjects();           

        foreach (var project in projects)
        {                
            try 
            {
                var buildConfigs = Client.BuildConfigsByProjectId(project.Id);

                foreach (var buildConfig in buildConfigs)
                {
                    var b = new BuildStatus();
                    var build = Client.LastBuildByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id);
                    var status = build.Status; // Used to loop through BuildConfigID's to find which is a FAILURE, SUCCESS, ERROR, or UNKNOWN

                    var change = Client.LastChangeDetailByBuildConfigId(buildConfig.Id); // Provides the changeID
                    var changeDetail = Client.ChangeDetailsByChangeId(change.Id); // Provides the username, this one populates the usernames

                    if (changeDetail != null)
                        b.user = changeDetail.Username;

                    b.id = buildConfig.Id.ToString();

                    // If the date isn't null place the start date in long format
                    if (build.StartDate != null)
                        b.date = build.StartDate.ToString();

                    // If block; set the status based on the BuildconfigID from the var status
                    if (status.Contains("FAILURE")){
                        b.status = "FAILURE";
                    }
                    else if (status.Contains("SUCCESS")){
                        b.status = "SUCCESS";
                    }
                    else if (status.Contains("ERROR")){
                        b.status = "ERROR";
                    }
                    else{
                        b.status = "UNKNOWN";
                    }
                    buildStatuses.Add(b);
                }

            } catch { }

        }
        var query = buildStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.status); // Create a sorted list from Error - Unknown               

        return Json(query, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then I copied the JsonConverter I linked you too.

On my Website I finally pulled apart the list of Json with.

```
 public JsonResult AllStatuses() //from the json called in the _client view
    {
        List<Client> clients = storeDB.Clients.Include("Projects").Include("Projects.Builds").ToList();
        var buildStatuses = new List<BuildStatus>();

        foreach (var client in clients) {
            // Network credentials
            // Used to get the Json Service request                         // URL here: client.ClientURL
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:81/Status/AllStatuses");
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            var responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.RegisterConverters((new[] { new DynamicJsonConverter() }));
            dynamic obj = serializer.Deserialize(responseString, typeof(object)) as dynamic;

            foreach (var objects in obj) // Pull apart the dynamic object
            {
                var id = objects.id;
                var status = objects.status;
                var date = objects.date;
                var user = objects.user;

                var bs = new BuildStatus();
                try
                {
                    bs.status = status;
                    bs.date = date;
                    bs.id = id;
                    bs.user = user;
                }
                catch { throw; }
                buildStatuses.Add(bs);
            }
        }              

        return Json(buildStatuses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go for a jQuery approach:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
alert(obj.in_reply_to_status_id_str.id_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](http://json.codeplex.com/) json libraryfor accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the DataContractJsonSerializer class available in .NET once you add a reference to System.Runtime.Serialization.

All you need to do is a create two DataContract classes.  Something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;

namespace MyNamespace
{
   [DataContract]
   public class TwitterObject
   {
      [DataMember(Name = "statuses")]
      public TwitterStatus[] Statuses { get; set; }
   }

   [DataContract]
   public class TwitterStatus
   {
       [DataMember(Name = "in_reply_to_status_id_str")]
       public string InReplyToStatusIdStr { get; set; }

       [DataMember(Name = "id_str")]
       public string IdStr { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Then from any other method you wish, you just have to use the DataContractJsonSerializer to build your JSON into a .NET object:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TwitterObject));

// assume the twitterResponse is the JSON you receive
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(twitterResponse));

var twitterJson = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(memoryStream) as TwitterObject;
```

There may be some typos, but this should give you the hint.  I'm currently working on an extensive synchronization between a server app and a website and this is the method I currently use for JSON communication between the two.  I've found the combination of DataContracts and DataContractJsonSerializer is easier to use than 3rd party libraries.